# multiline for loop in IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am trying to do a multiline for loop in IDL but its not working, here is my first program:

```
for n=0,5 do begin
  print, n
```

which gives this output:

```
6
```

and this is my second program:

```
for n=0,5 do begin
  print, n
endfor
```

which gives the following error:

```
endfor
 ^
% Syntax error.
```

I would like the program to gives this output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to write a multi-line `FOR` loop is indeed:

```
for n=0,5 do begin
  print, n
endfor
```

But IDL doesn’t accept multi-line statements with `BEGIN`/`END` blocks in all contexts. For instance, not directly at the command-line. If you want to do that at the command-line, you would need to create a small main-level program by doing:

```
IDL> .run
for n=0,5 do begin
  print, n
endfor
end
```

You could also use a `FOR` loop like that in a procedure or function.

Answer (score 1):

as @SofCh above suggests, i just use the continuation characters to do this

```
for n=0,5 do begin $ 
  print, n & $ 
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing it in the command line you may need to add a '&' or '&$' at the end of the 'DO BEGIN' line. This indicates that the loop continues on the next line.

But also its usually easier to just condense it to one line, e.g.

```
    for n = 0,5 do print, n
```